# C - Copy structures with dynamics arrays

Tags: c, copy, structure, dynamic-arrays

Having a structure of this type, how can one structure be copied into another one. I declared `Array first` and `Array second`, then I initilized both and put different data in each one.

Then to copy `first` to `second` I tried `second = first` but it doesn't work.

How can I do it?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <inttypes.h>


    //////////////////////////////////////

    typedef struct {

      int group[8];
      uint64_t points;

    } BestGroup;

    //////////////////////////////////////

    typedef struct {
      BestGroup *array;
      size_t used;
      size_t size;
    } Array;

    void initArray(Array *a, size_t initialSize) {
      a->array = (BestGroup *)malloc(initialSize * sizeof(BestGroup));
      a->used = 0;
      a->size = initialSize;
    }

    void insertArray(Array *a, int *group_add, uint64_t points_add) {

      // a->used is the number of used entries, because a->array[a->used++] updates a->used only *after* the array has been accessed.
      // Therefore a->used can go up to a->size 
      if (a->used == a->size) 
      {
        a->size *= 2;
        a->array = (BestGroup *)realloc(a->array, a->size * sizeof(BestGroup));
      }

      int i; 
      for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
      {
        a->array[a->used].group[i] = group_add[i];
      }
      a->array[a->used].points = points_add;
      a->used++;
    }

    void freeArray(Array *a) {
      free(a->array);
      a->array = NULL;
      a->used = a->size = 0;
    }


    void CopyArray(Array *a, Array *b)
    {
        b = a;
    }

    int main()
    {
        Array first;
        Array second;

        int first_data[8] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
        int second_data[8] = {7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0};

        initArray(&first, 2);
        initArray(&second, 2);

        insertArray(&first, first_data, 5);
        insertArray(&first, first_data, 5);
        insertArray(&first, first_data, 5);

        insertArray(&second, second_data, 2);

        ///////////////////////////////////////////

        printf("Total Points: %" PRIu64 "\n", first.array->points);
        printf("Number: %lu\n\n", first.used);
        printf("\n");

        int i;
        int j;

        for (i = 0; i < first.used; i++)
        {

          printf("[");

          for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
          {
            if (j) printf(", ");
            printf("%d", first.array[i].group[j]);
          }

          printf("]\n");
        }

        ////////////////////////////////////////////

        printf("\n");
        printf("Total Points: %" PRIu64 "\n", second.array->points);
        printf("Number: %lu\n\n", second.used);
        printf("\n");

        for (i = 0; i < second.used; i++)
        {

          printf("[");

          for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
          {
            if (j) printf(", ");
            printf("%d", second.array[i].group[j]);
          }

          printf("]\n");
        }

        /////////////////////////////////

        CopyArray(&first, &second);


        printf("\n");
        printf("\n");
        printf("\n");
        printf("\n");

        ///////////////////////////////////////////

        printf("Total Points: %" PRIu64 "\n", first.array->points);
        printf("Number: %lu\n\n", first.used);
        printf("\n");

        for (i = 0; i < first.used; i++)
        {

          printf("[");

          for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
          {
            if (j) printf(", ");
            printf("%d", first.array[i].group[j]);
          }

          printf("]\n");
        }

        ////////////////////////////////////////////

        printf("\n");
        printf("Total Points: %" PRIu64 "\n", second.array->points);
        printf("Number: %lu\n\n", second.used);
        printf("\n");

        for (i = 0; i < second.used; i++)
        {

          printf("[");

          for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
          {
            if (j) printf(", ");
            printf("%d", second.array[i].group[j]);
          }

          printf("]\n");
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

The output is:

```
Total Points: 5
Number: 3


[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

Total Points: 2
Number: 1


[7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]




Total Points: 5
Number: 3


[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

Total Points: 2
Number: 1


[7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

When it should end with the last list as:

```
Total Points: 5
Number: 3


[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

Total Points: 5
Number: 3


[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

**EDIT**

As suggested I used memcpy(), so I changed the `CopyArray()` function to:

```
    void CopyArray(Array *a, Array *b)
    {
        // b = a;
        memcpy(b, a, a->size * sizeof(BestGroup));
    }
```

It looks like the result is going to be fine, until it reaches the end of the program and outputs

`*** stack smashing detected ***`

Comment: Where is the corresponding line in the above code ? It should work if they have the same type (You can try memcpy() as already suggested).

Comment: The majority of the code you've presented appears irrelevant to the question.  We do like to see code, but generally we want a [mcve], with emphasis, in this case, on "*minimal*".  But do not neglect "complete".  It's not clear what "it doesn't work" means here, or how you determine that.  In particular, you absolutely can use the `=` operator to copy the value of a whole structure to another structure of the same type.

Comment: Just added the main function to the question as well as both the actual and the expected outputs

Comment: You almost certainly need to revise the copy function to allocate memory fort the array component, and then copy the array from the old to the new.  You know how big a space to allocate from the other members of the structure to be copied.  If you don't do it this way, you have two structures pointing to the same unit of allocated space, which makes the memory management hell unless you're willing to leak all the memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code produces the answer you want.  The `CopyArray()` function now releases the data already in `b`, then initializes `b`, and finally copies the data from `a` to `b`.  There are places where the code uses `8` but should probably use a different variable for the size — I've annotated them in this code.  The `dump_array()` function is an exemplar of a function that I routinely write and use when debugging a complex structure.  It takes a tag string (which allows you to identify which call it is that is printing) plus the object to be printed.  I often take a file stream argument too, and in case of doubt, add a `fflush()` for the output stream.

```
/* SO 4639-4467 */
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    int group[8];
    uint64_t points;
} BestGroup;

typedef struct
{
    BestGroup *array;
    size_t used;
    size_t size;
} Array;

static void initArray(Array *a, size_t initialSize)
{
    a->array = (BestGroup *)malloc(initialSize * sizeof(BestGroup));
    a->used = 0;
    a->size = initialSize;
}

static void insertArray(Array *a, const int *group_add, uint64_t points_add)
{
    if (a->used == a->size)
    {
        a->size *= 2;
        a->array = (BestGroup *)realloc(a->array, a->size * sizeof(BestGroup));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)     // Why 8 and not points_add?
    {
        a->array[a->used].group[i] = group_add[i];
    }
    a->array[a->used].points = points_add;
    a->used++;
}

static void freeArray(Array *a)
{
    free(a->array);
    a->array = NULL;
    a->used = a->size = 0;
}

static void CopyArray(const Array *a, Array *b)
{
    freeArray(b);
    initArray(b, a->used);
    memmove(b->array, a->array, a->used * sizeof(a->array[0]));
    b->used = a->used;
}

static void dump_array(const char *tag, const Array *arr)
{
    printf("Array: %s\n", tag);
    printf("Total Points: %" PRIu64 "\n", arr->array->points);
    printf("Number: %lu\n", arr->used);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < arr->used; i++)
    {
        printf("[");
        for (size_t j = 0; j < 8; j++)  // Why 8 and not arr->array[i].points?
        {
            if (j)
                printf(", ");
            printf("%d", arr->array[i].group[j]);
        }
        printf("]\n");
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

int main(void)
{
    Array first;
    Array second;

    int first_data[8] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
    int second_data[8] = {7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0};

    initArray(&first, 2);
    initArray(&second, 2);

    insertArray(&first, first_data, 5);
    insertArray(&first, first_data, 5);
    insertArray(&first, first_data, 5);
    insertArray(&second, second_data, 2);

    dump_array("first", &first);
    dump_array("second", &second);

    CopyArray(&first, &second);

    printf("\n");
    dump_array("first", &first);
    dump_array("second", &second);

    return 0;
}
```

The output from running this is:

```
Array: first
Total Points: 5
Number: 3
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

Array: second
Total Points: 2
Number: 1
[7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]


Array: first
Total Points: 5
Number: 3
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

Array: second
Total Points: 5
Number: 3
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```